# DHCP complicates using IP Address Source in Amazon EC2 Security group settings

Tags: networking, amazon-web-services, dhcp

### **Background:**

I am learning to setup my amazon web services account. I watched a video tutorial(http://youtu.be/-xVyuLJZFYc), where they mention that within the security groups dashboard, one could block-off(or allow) access by protocol, port, and ip-address.

---

### **Problem:**

My internet service provider uses DHCP(http://www.myaccount.charter.com/customers/support.aspx?supportarticleid=49). To my understanding, this means that my ip address is going to be changed regularly by the dhcp service.

This seems to be a problem, because if I wanted to only allow my desktop computer to have access (by specifying my IP address ), then my IP address would be changed to some value I cannot anticipate, then I would need to manually change the group settings each time.

---

### **Question:**

Are there any techniques, tools or workarounds that are well suited to help me add my IP address within the amazon security group settings, such that I would not need to constantly adjust the settings to account for DHCP?

---

### **Note:**

Also If my networking knowledge seems lacking, please feel free to include general conceptual ideas (or resources).

Comment: Before you try to solve this "problem," make sure it actually is a problem.  The fact that the IP address is theoretically dynamic and whether or not it ever actually changes are two almost unrelated topics.  It's easy enough to check your current external IP, so instead of speculating, just check it.  Monitor it.  See if it's changing or not.  I have systems that have run for years with "dynamic" addresses that just never seem to change.

Comment: How did you go with this? Do you need more detail or do you have any follow up questions?

Comment: @DrewKhoury Since I am merely dabbling in EC2, I don't have a major problem. If I really needed to overcome the problem, I would probably just get a static IP. Thanks for all your contributions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Static IP

If locking down access based on your IP is a priority, then obtain a static IP.

#### Dynamic IP - Update Firewall Manually

If you don't want to pay for a static IP, update the security group rules when your IP changes.

You can do this manually.

#### Dynamic IP - Update Firewall via script

You could create a script on your computer that monitors your IP Address and updates your AWS account with the new IP address (although you'll have to determine if this is an acceptable security risk).

#### Port Knocking

You might also be interested in using port knocking (again you'll have to determine if this an acceptable security risk):

> Port knocking is a method of externally opening ports on a firewall by
>   generating a connection attempt on a set of prespecified closed ports.
>   Once a correct sequence of connection attempts is received, the
>   firewall rules are dynamically modified to allow the host which sent
>   the connection attempts to connect over specific port(s).

#### SSH Access

If we're talking about SSH there are a number of other security measures you should be considering:

- Use a private/public key-pair for SSH access
- Have SSH listen on a separate network interface (keeps your service away from snooping eyes)
- Don't allow root ssh access, in-fact only allow specific users/groups access to ssh
- Mitigate brute force attacks with software, something like fail2ban

Answer (score -2):

Honestly, security by IP address is asking for problems and insecurity unless you're incredibly careful about how it's setup. In your case, don't.

Pick a really good password. Use something like http://www.passwordmeter.com/ to help you pick one. If it doesn't rate at 100% on that website, don't use it. Also, consider using 32+ characters of completely random garbage, keep the password in a password program (don't forget to backup the program).

Also, anything that can be used to recover your account, security questions and the like, answer them with random garbage as well, keep these "Answers" in the notes of your password program from above.

Comment: I don't agree with your recommendation of passwordmeter.com.  I put in a random password of length 9 with upper, lower, numbers, and special chars, and got a score of a 100.  I put in a random password with 18 lower chars and got a score of only 23%, even though it has a search space 48 million times larger than the shorter password.  Also, it's completely unnecessary to have a random password of length 32, unless you're using ones and zeros.

Comment: Does not answer the question at all.

Comment: Sometimes the correct answer is "Don't do that". Also, people don't usually pick passwords based on bits of entropy; rating a password should incorporate that dynamic.

Comment: It's common and recommended in the AWS environment to restrict admin access in the way that the OP is doing.  You might be confusing the EC2 security group firewall with a firewall internal to an instance.

Comment: If security by IP is an issue then security by passwords is a bigger one! If we are talking ssh then it has to be mentioned that private keys beat passwords hands down. Also private keys + IP restrictions is a sound security practice. If it's something other than ssh access, let's say wordpress admin, passwords become important ... But adding IP restriction, particularly to admin areas is perfectly sound advice. Your post seems to be missing a big chunk of the picture.

Comment: @DrewKhoury I've also seen many more people lock themselves out of accounts because they didn't know exactly what they were getting themselves into. Considering the OP is a user/developer, not a sysadmin, and first time user of IP restrictions, would you honestly recommend they just dive in? Your points about passwords being a security problem is poignant and accurate - but I think newcomers to security should either ease into tighter restrictions or get someone involved who really understands the implications of the security settings.

Comment: Setting IP restrictions (via security groups) can be easily reverted. You'll always have acces to them via the web console and CLI. I would encourage everyone consider IP restrictions, but more importantly if we're talking about ssh access on boxes I would encourage no passwords and private keys instead.